# How to get the (x,y) coordinates given a index when x < y?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

In the past I've often used loops of the following kind (Haskell example):

```
  upperBoundToTuples :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
  upperBoundToTuples n = [(x,y) | x <- [0..n], y <- [x+1..n]]
```

The above code produces tuples of range (0,1)..(n,n) where for all x < y.

I was wondering if it there was an efficient way of getting those (x,y) indices given a single index? Possible applications include optimization problems on the GPU where loops are not allowed and each thread only gets an index.

Also if it is possible for the 2D case, could such an algorithm be generalized to multiple dimensions?

Comment: What does it mean "getting those `(x, y)` indices given a single index?"? Do you want a function like `getPair :: Int -> (Int, Int)` that given a number `i` returns the `i`th pair where the pair are ordered in a certain way? Or what?

Comment: @Bakuriu Both of the answer have the gist of it. You did get my question right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking for a bijection from [0, N(N+1)/2) to pairs (x, y) with 0 <= x < y <= N.

Here's one simple way to define it (in pseudocode, but should be trivial to convert to Haskell):

```
x0, y0 = i / (N + 1), i % (N + 1)
if x0 < y0 then result = (x0, y0)
else result = (N - 1 - x0, N - y0)
```

Here's a visualisation of the function for N=6. The map is laid out in a table with rows of length N+1=7, with the first row representing the value of the function for i=0 to 6, the next i=7 to 13 and so on. If you look very closely and carefully, you can see that things above the leading diagonal map to their own location in the table, and things on or below the diagonal map rotationally to the later entries.

```
5,6  0,1  0,2  0,3  0,4  0,5  0,6
4,6  4,5  1,2  1,3  1,4  1,5  1,6
3,6  3,5  3,4  2,3  2,4  2,5  2,6
```

And here's the opposite of this visualisation: a table `T` of size (N+1) by (N+1) with `T[x, y] = i` where `i` is mapped to (x, y) by the function above.

```
 -   1   2   3   4   5   6
 -   -   9  10  11  12  13
 -   -   -  17  18  19  20
 -   -   -   -  16  15  14
 -   -   -   -   -   8   7
 -   -   -   -   -   -   0
 -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

### Higher dimensions

This method can probably be made to work in higher dimensions, but I don't immediately see how. As an alternative, here's a simple but somewhat inefficient method that does work in arbitrary dimensions.

First, note there's `choose(N + 1, k)` increasing sequences of length `k` from the numbers from `0` to `N` (where `choose(N, k)` is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)). Of those, `choose(N, k - 1)` of them end with `N`. That gives this recursive function that generates the sequences in descending colexicographical order (again in pseudocode):

```
sequence(N, k, index)
    = []                                           if k == 0
    = sequence(N - 1, k - 1, index) + [N]          if index < choose(N, k - 1)
    = sequence(N - 1, k, index - choose(N, k - 1)) otherwise
```

Here's, `sequence(5, 3, index)` for `index` between 0 and 19:

```
 0 -> [3, 4, 5]
 1 -> [2, 4, 5]
 2 -> [1, 4, 5]
 3 -> [0, 4, 5]
 4 -> [2, 3, 5]
 5 -> [1, 3, 5]
 6 -> [0, 3, 5]
 7 -> [1, 2, 5]
 8 -> [0, 2, 5]
 9 -> [0, 1, 5]
10 -> [2, 3, 4]
11 -> [1, 3, 4]
12 -> [0, 3, 4]
13 -> [1, 2, 4]
14 -> [0, 2, 4]
15 -> [0, 1, 4]
16 -> [1, 2, 3]
17 -> [0, 2, 3]
18 -> [0, 1, 3]
19 -> [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: This is a pretty ingenious way of doing it. And actually, now that I look at it for larger loops, it is half sorted so the cache locality would only be a problem for a single warp. Does there exist a similar algorithm for 3D and more?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic I guess it can be made to work for dimension > 2, but the details are fiddly enough to put me off doing the work to figure it out. I've added an arbitrary dimensional alternative solution to the answer.

Comment: I was thinking that something like in your later example would be possible, but it did not see how until you posted it even though I did something similar in the past. At any rate, the 2D case is the most common application of this by far, so it is all good. I accepted your answer before seeing the added algorithm for higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

We may equivalently consider [`[(x,y) | x<-[0..n], y<-[0..x-1]]`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). This list has length

*ℓ*<sub>*n*</sub> = <sub>*x*=0</sub>∑<sup>*n*</sup> *x*
[= <sup>*n*·(*n*+1)</sup>/<sub>2</sub>](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html).

Hence we can get, to a given *ℓ*, the nearest lower *n* through

2·*ℓ*<sub>*n*</sub> = *n*·(*n*+1) = *n*<sup>2</sup> + *n*

*n*<sub>~</sub> = -½ ± √(¼ + 2·*ℓ<sub>n</sub>*)

In particular, for a given index *i*,

*n*<sub>*i*−</sub> = ⌊-½ ± √(¼ + 2·*i*)⌋

is the x-length of the last fully completed triangle. Thus, the index *i* lies in the row *n*<sub>*i*−</sub>+1. That triangle had an area of

*ℓ*<sub>*n*<sub>*i*−</sub></sub> = <sup>*n*<sub>*i*−</sub>·(*n*<sub>*i*−</sub>+1)</sup>/<sub>2</sub>

which we therefore need to subtract from *i* to get the remainder index (in y-direction). This gives rise to the definition

```
lowerTriangularTuple :: Int -> (Int,Int)
lowerTriangularTuple i = (nmin+1, i - (nmin*(nmin+1))`div`2)
 where nmin = floor $ -1/2 + sqrt(1/4 + 2 * fromIntegral i)
```

Example:

```
GHCi> lowerTriangularTuple <$> [0..30]
[(1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(5,0),(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(6,0),(6,1),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4),(6,5),(7,0),(7,1),(7,2),(7,3),(7,4),(7,5),(7,6),(8,0),(8,1),(8,2)]
```

Comment: I had not expected that I could get the answer to this via the quadratic equation. Your answer has the benefit of being sorted and not requiring the upper bound. Being sorted in particular is good for cache locality. It would be perfect if not for that expensive `sqrt`. That having said, I think it needs to be elaborated more. I do not understand why solving the quadratic equation and then taking the floor of it gives the correct answer. Neither do I understand the `(nmin+1, i - (nmin*(nmin+1)) div 2)` part.

Comment: I explained some more. — Pretty sure it would be possible to replace the square root with some faster approximation, but I'm not sure about the stability.

Comment: What sort of triangles are we talking about here? It is not clear to me what connection they have with this problem. Keep in mind, I am not a mathematician and neither are most of the programmers who will look at the question. Maybe you could post some references for this problem if it would be too long to explain on SO. Motivated by the replies, I took a look myself at the pairing functions articles on the net, but I could only find information for non-ordered pairs.

Comment: Ok, it clicked for me. Having some pictures on that Wiki page helped. First you minimze the n via the quadratic equation which turns out to be x and then calculate y by substracting i from the remainder. Brilliant. I am going to accept Paul Hankin's answer as it would be more efficient in practice, but your answer did give a lot to think about. Thanks.